# User-defined implicit conversion operator and overload resolution

Tags: c++

Today I experienced an interesting behaviour with user-defined implicit conversion operators.

Let's take this piece of code:

```
struct Widget {
    Widget(uint64_t) {

    }

    Widget(const std::string &) {

    }

    operator uint64_t() {
        return static_cast<uint64_t>(123456789UL);
    }

    operator std::string() {
        return std::string("Hello");
    }
};
```

A basic struct which can implicitly be converted to either a uint64_t or a std::string.

Now, try to print out a Widget instance through std::cout :

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using std::cout;
    Widget w(123456);

    cout << w;
}
```

For whatever reason, the Widget will always be converted to a uint64_t. At first I would expect the call to be ambiguous, and be qualifed with a standard explicit conversion to compile :

```
int main() {
    using std::cout;
    Widget w(123456);

    cout << static_cast<uint64_t>(w);
```

}

But for a reason I'm ignoring right now, operator uint64_t is selected. I tried to look at the C++ specification, but couldn't find anything useful to answer my question.

Can anyone help me figuring out what is the compiler doing with overload resolution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`uint64_t` conversion is preferred. The reason is simply that `<<` is overloaded as template for `strings` (basic_strings). Compilers will always prefer exact match over templates on overload resolution.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that operator<< was overloaded as a template for std::basic_string. It explains it all. If I replace std::string by double it is now ambiguous

Comment: @octal http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt

Answer (score 4):

Of course you can find it in C++ specification.

Read *Overload Resolution* in `§13.3.1/2` and `§13.3.1/3`

> Overload resolution selects the function to call in seven distinct
>   contexts within the language...

> - First, a subset of the candidate functions (those that have the proper number of arguments and meet certain other conditions) is
>     selected to form a set of viable functions (13.3.2).
> - Then the best viable function is selected based on the implicit conversion sequences (13.3.3.1) needed to match each argument to the
>     corresponding parameter of each viable function.

In brief, compiler first lists candidates to use, then tries to find best fit and more efficient overload.